# get all record without child and not mapped any parent to in self referencing table ? - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle

I have a self-referencing table with content like this:
[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f5a60/1)
Self-referencing parent table

```
 emp_id man_id(FK of emp_id or ParentID)
    ---------------------
    1   (null)
    2   (null)
    3   (null)
    4   2
    5   2
    6   3
    7   3
    8   1
    9   (null)
    10  (null)
    11  (null)
```

help me whit SQL statement For :(emp_id which do not having any relations)

```
emp_id
-----
9
10
11
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f5a60/1)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Oracle or SQL Server? Those are two very different DBMS

Answer (score 2):

Try like this;

```
select e.emp_id from emp e where 
e.man_id is null and e.emp_id 
not in (select distinct man_id from emp where man_id is not null)
```

Another option is using `left join`;

```
select e.emp_id from emp e 
left join emp e2 ON e.emp_id = e2.man_id 
where e2.man_id is null and e.man_id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` to locate the records that are not referenced as `man_id`

```
   select e.emp_id, e.man_id from emp e
   left outer join emp e1 on e1.man_id = e.emp_id
   where e1.emp_id is null
```

If you also want to constrain the results so that the emp_id does not have a man_id, you can do:

```
   select e.emp_id, e.man_id from emp e
   left outer join emp e1 on e1.man_id = e.emp_id
   where e1.emp_id is null and e.man_id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can two rules to be taken care of -
1. If an `emp_id` is present in `man_id` column, it should be excluded from the results
2. If an `emp_id` has some `man_id` mapped to it, it should be excluded from the results

This can be done using a left-join on self.

```
SELECT A.EMP_ID
FROM
EMP A LEFT JOIN EMP B
ON A.EMP_ID = B.MAN_ID
WHERE A.MAN_ID IS NULL AND B.MAN_ID IS NULL;
```

The first `WHERE` condition will take care of rule 1 and second `WHERE` will take care of rule 2.